# Get redirected URL from Postman

Tags: javascript, postman, redirect, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I'm currently migrating my old website to a new one and I have just created some url redirect rules to redirect old links to their pages on the new website.

In order to test these redirect rules I'm using Postman but I can't find any way of getting the redirected url from Postman's [scripts documentation](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference/). `REDIRECTED_URL` is the url after being processed by the redirect rule.

Here is my current test:

```
var root_url = postman.getEnvironmentVariable('root_url');
var oldurl = root_url + postman.getEnvironmentVariable('old_page');
var newurl = root_url + postman.getEnvironmentVariable('new_page');

if (REDIRECTED_URL == newurl)
{
    tests[oldurl + " redirected"] = true;
}
else
{
    tests[oldurl + " failed to redirect"] = false;
}
```

Is there a way to test this in postman or should I be using another application?

Comment: I'm not sure about your specific question but what status code do you get (or return since it's your website)?

Comment: i'm getting status code 200s and 404s back because not all the pages are built yet.

Comment: I'm redirecting a page like
`example.com/test-page/test01`
to
`example.com/tests/test01`

so regardless if the page exists or not I want to check if the url is correctly redirecting

Comment: and when you redirect is the status code 302? can you try it on another website that redirects?

Comment: @Maayao I am getting status code 301 (permanant redirects) back when debugging in chrome and preserving the log but in postman it only shows me status code 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Switch off the setting `Automatically follow redirects` in Postman.
2. Do a request to `example.com/test-page/test01`
3. In the test tab, check if the https status code and the re-direct header are correct:

```
pm.test("Status Code is 301", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(301);
});

pm.test("Location-header exists", function () {
    pm.expect(postman.getResponseHeader("Location")).to.eq("example.com/tests/test01");
});
```

Comment: perfect! thank you so much. The 'automatically follow redirects' setting being 'on' was causing the issue